# SQL Server : Select query working but not the updating one. Subquery Problem

Tags: t-sql, subquery

I have a problem with an update query.

Here is an extract of the table I try to use for updating an other table named BOARD_CALLS

*TABLE: BOARD_TASKS*

```
   CHAR(8)     BIGINT      INT        INT           CHAR(8)             INT
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| REF_CALL  | NUM_TASK | IS_PHONE | IS_EMAIL | IS_DUPLICATE_WITH | IS_DUPLICATE |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-345  | TASK3451 |    1     |    0     |        NULL       |       0      |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-345  | TASK3452 |    1     |    0     |        NULL       |       0      |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-345  | TASK3453 |    0     |    0     |      CALL-344     |       1      |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-346  | TASK3461 |    1     |    1     |        NULL       |       0      |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-347  | TASK3471 |    1     |    1     |        NULL       |       0      |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-347  | TASK3472 |    0     |    1     |        NULL       |       0      |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-348  | TASK3481 |    0     |    0     |      CALL-346     |       1      |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
```

I use two rules :

When at least one IS_PHONE / IS_EMAIL / IS_DUPLICATE = 1 then IS_PHONE / IS_EMAIL / IS_DUPLICATE on the destination table = 1
Else 0

When IS_DUPLICATE_WITH is not null then I need to fill IS_DUPLICATE_WITH with the call number

When I do a select on BOARD_TASKS, everything works fine and the result match what I want

**Here the result :**

*TABLE : BOARD_CALLS*

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| REF_CALL  | IS_PHONE | IS_EMAIL | IS_DUPLICATE_WITH | IS_DUPLICATE |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-345  |    1     |    0     |      CALL-344     |       1      |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-346  |    1     |    1     |        NULL       |       0      |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-347  |    1     |    1     |        NULL       |       0      |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
| CALL-348  |    0     |    0     |      CALL-346     |       1      |
+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
```

**Here the select query I use :**

```
SELECT REF_CALL,

MAX(IS_DUPLICATE_WITH) IS_DUPLICATE_WITH,
CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_PHONE = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_PHONE,
CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_EMAIL = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_EMAIL,
CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_DUPLICATE = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_DUPLICATE

FROM BOARD_TASKS
WHERE IS_DUPLICATE_WITH IS NOT NULL 
OR IS_DUPLICATE = 1
OR IS_DUPLICATE = 0
OR IS_DUPLICATE IS NULL
GROUP BY REF_CALL
```

But as soon as I try to update BOARD_CALLS I've got 2 error messages

*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=*

*null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other set operation*

**Here my update query**

```
UPDATE T1

SET


T1.IS_DUPLICATE_WITH = (SELECT MAX(IS_DUPLICATE_WITH) 
                        FROM BOARD_TASKS WHERE IS_DUPLICATE_WITH IS NOT NULL 
                        OR IS_DUPLICATE = 1 
                        OR IS_DUPLICATE = 0 
                        OR IS_DUPLICATE IS NULL 
                        GROUP BY REF_CALL),

T1.IS_PHONE = (SELECT 
              (CASE WHEN 
               COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_PHONE = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
               FROM BOARD_TASKS 
               GROUP BY REF_CALL),

T1.IS_EMAIL = (SELECT 
              (CASE WHEN 
               COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_EMAIL = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
               FROM BOARD_TASKS 
               GROUP BY REF_CALL),

T1.IS_DUPLICATE = (SELECT 
                  (CASE WHEN 
                   COUNT(CASE WHEN BOARD_TASKS.IS_DUPLICATE = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                   FROM BOARD_TASKS 
                   GROUP BY REF_CALL)

FROM BOARD_CALLS T1
INNER JOIN BOARD_TASKS T2 ON T1.REF_CALL = T2.REF_CALL
```

**BOARD_CALLS** already has default values on each column

*REF_CALL : Automaticaly filled when a new call is created (PK)*

*IS_PHONE / IS_EMAIL / IS_DUPLICATE : 0*

*IS_DUPLICATE_WITH : NULL*

I really don't know why It's working with a select but not an update

Comment: Aside: Comparing `int` values to strings, e.g. `CASE WHEN IS_PHONE = '1'`, is a bad habit.

Comment: Hello. Yes I don't know why I did that. I've corrected that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is pretty specific, you are trying to update a column with a query that clearly returns more than one row.  You showed that in your select statement at the start of the post.
For Example this part of your UPDATE statement:

> ```
> T1.IS_DUPLICATE_WITH = (SELECT MAX(IS_DUPLICATE_WITH) 
>                         FROM BOARD_TASKS WHERE IS_DUPLICATE_WITH IS NOT NULL 
>                         OR IS_DUPLICATE = 1 
>                         OR IS_DUPLICATE = 0 
>                         OR IS_DUPLICATE IS NULL 
>                         GROUP BY REF_CALL)
> ```

Is trying to force all of the values of that query into one value. That is what the optimizer is trying to tell you.

ALSO, I am not sure all of the possible values for IS_DUPLICATE but it appears that you are listing all of them. If so, then you don't need any of them in the WHERE clause.

TRY THIS, I don't have any DDL so there may be syntax errors but it should get you most of the way there:

```
UPDATE BOARDCALLS 
    SET IS_DUPLICATE_WITH = t2.IS_DUPLICATE_WITH,
        IS_PHONE = t2.IS_PHONE,
        IS_EMAIL = t2.IS_EMAIL,
        IS_DUPLICATE = t2.IS_DUPLICATE
FROM BOARDCALLS t1
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT REF_CALL,
            MAX(IS_DUPLICATE_WITH) IS_DUPLICATE_WITH,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_PHONE = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_PHONE,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_EMAIL = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_EMAIL,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_DUPLICATE = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_DUPLICATE

            FROM BOARD_TASKS
            WHERE IS_DUPLICATE_WITH IS NOT NULL 
            OR IS_DUPLICATE = 1
            OR IS_DUPLICATE = 0
            OR IS_DUPLICATE IS NULL
            GROUP BY REF_CALL) t2 ON t1.REF_CALL = t2.REF_CALL
```

Comment: It's worked great. The problem with the subquery is corrected. I should have thinking of doing a "inner join" :( . The other message "null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other set operation" is corrected to. It's because some NUM_TASK contain only NULL value instead of 1 and 0. And IS_DUPLICATE has more value than 0, 1 or NULL because there is a bug on the software related to this DB writing garbage datas on the DB.. Anyway thank you very much for your help.